# Apache Spark 2.0: Expression-string to orderBy() / sort() column in descending order

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking at a book example similar to the following (virtually identical):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as sFn
>>>   # Note: I import Spark functions this way to avoid name collisions w/ Python.
>>>   # Usage below: sFn.expr(), sFn.col(), etc.

>>> col0 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> col1 = [4, 5, 6, 7]

>>> myDF = spark.createDataFrame(zip(col0, col1),
                                 schema=['col0', 'col1'])
>>> print(myDF)
>>> myDF.show()
>>> myDF.orderBy(sFn.expr('col0 desc')).show() # <--- Problem line. Doesn't descend.
```

Now the book example claims that the last statement would order by `col0` in descending fashion, but it does not:

```
DataFrame[col0: bigint, col1: bigint]

+----+----+
|col0|col1|
+----+----+
|   0|   4|
|   1|   5|
|   2|   6|
|   3|   7|
+----+----+

+----+----+
|col0|col1|
+----+----+
|   0|   4|
|   1|   5|
|   2|   6|
|   3|   7|
+----+----+
```

This syntax variant, however, has always worked for me:

```
myDF.orderBy(sFn.col("col0").desc()).show()
```

Is the problematic variation above a typo or errata? And if it is a typo or errata, what tweak is necessary to make it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `sFn.expr('col0 desc')`, `desc` is translated as an alias instead of an `order by` `modifier`, as you can see by typing it in the console:

```py
sFn.expr('col0 desc')
# Column<col0 AS `desc`>
```

And here are several other options you can choose from depending on what you need:

```
 myDF.orderBy('col0', ascending=0).show()
+----+----+
|col0|col1|
+----+----+
|   3|   7|
|   2|   6|
|   1|   5|
|   0|   4|
+----+----+


myDF.orderBy(sFn.desc('col0')).show()
+----+----+
|col0|col1|
+----+----+
|   3|   7|
|   2|   6|
|   1|   5|
|   0|   4|
+----+----+

myDF.orderBy(myDF.col0.desc()).show()
+----+----+
|col0|col1|
+----+----+
|   3|   7|
|   2|   6|
|   1|   5|
|   0|   4|
+----+----+
```

Comment: Like you demonstrated, I evaluated it, too, and tried to add `AS` to the string as well, which did not do anything. It looks like a book error. I like your variations. Accepted as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Having never loved `SQL` (because directives and keywords are sloppily interspersed with identifiers), I prefer the DataFrame API; and the variations above will provide visitors with clear samples (which they can apply to variations of this post). IMHO. =:)

Comment: Agree. SQL syntax is flexible but could become quite difficult to maintain and reason about later on as the code stacks up.